# Recognize encoding type

Tags: php, decode, encode

I have this encoded string:

```
%E1%F0%E9+%E1%F8%F7%2C+%E2%E1%F2%FA%E9%E9%ED%2C+%E7%E5%E5%FA+%F9%EC%ED%2C+%F8%EE%FA+%E2%EF%2C+%FA%EC+%E0%E1%E9%E1+%E9%F4%E5+%28%E0%E6%F2%F7%E4+%E7%EC%F7%E9%FA%29%2C+%E6%E9%F7%E9%ED%2C+%EB%F8%EE%E9%E4
```

I want to use php (mb_convert_encoding probably) to convert this string to look good.

The string should be this:

`בני ברק, גבעתיים, חוות שלם, רמת גן, תל אביב יפו (אזעקה חלקית), זיקים, כרמיה`

The problem is that I don't know what encoding is it.

**I receive this data by POST method, it looks like it is URL encoded, but urldecode() isnt working**

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like a UTF-16 character set. Which one: Encode your string and see if it matches.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen I got: `??? ???, ???????, ???? ???, ??? ??, ?? ???? ??? (????? ?????), ?????, ?????` when I used: `echo mb_convert_encoding($_POST['cities'], "UTF-16", "UTF-8");`

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen I've tried to convert the hebrew string to UTF-16 and it looks similar, but it's not the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hrmm that looks like url-encoding and comparing the input and expected output it's a single-byte encoding, and it's definietely not ASCII,
>
> *google "hebrew encoding"*
>
> Ahh, Windows-1255

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=Windows-1255');
$str = '%E1%F0%E9+%E1%F8%F7%2C+%E2%E1%F2%FA%E9%E9%ED%2C+%E7%E5%E5%FA+%F9%EC%ED%2C+%F8%EE%FA+%E2%EF%2C+%FA%EC+%E0%E1%E9%E1+%E9%F4%E5+%28%E0%E6%F2%F7%E4+%E7%EC%F7%E9%FA%29%2C+%E6%E9%F7%E9%ED%2C+%EB%F8%EE%E9%E4';
echo urldecode($str);
```

Output:

> בני ברק, גבעתיים, חוות שלם, רמת גן, תל אביב יפו (אזעקה חלקית), זיקים, כרמיה

### Edit:

`mb_convert_encoding()` wouldn't work for me, but `iconv()` appears to have done the trick:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$str = '%E1%F0%E9+%E1%F8%F7%2C+%E2%E1%F2%FA%E9%E9%ED%2C+%E7%E5%E5%FA+%F9%EC%ED%2C+%F8%EE%FA+%E2%EF%2C+%FA%EC+%E0%E1
%E9%E1+%E9%F4%E5+%28%E0%E6%F2%F7%E4+%E7%EC%F7%E9%FA%29%2C+%E6%E9%F7%E9%ED%2C+%EB%F8%EE%E9%E4';
$dec = iconv('Windows-1255', 'UTF-8', urldecode($str));
?><html>
<body>
<p><?= $dec ?></p>
<p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog</p>
</html>
```

Output:

> בני ברק, גבעתיים, חוות שלם, רמת גן, תל אביב יפו (אזעקה חלקית), זיקים,
>   כרמיה
>
> The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog

Now you just need to make sure that *everything* on your page is UTF-8, but at least pretty much everything should "play nicely" with each other. More or less. Most of the time...

Fun fact: The other 8-bit Hebrew encoding you might run into is [ISO/IEC 8859-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-8) which appears to be quite different, though much less common.

Comment: Ok it looks right when I set the header like that, but the problem is that the whole page is encoded differently so it messes it up. is there a way to convert this string to UTF-8? thanks!

Comment: @Sven I got confused, I meant mb_convert_encoding.. Fixed

Comment: I know text is bad transporting ironic comments. Use `iconv()` to convert encoding. Personally I avoid the `mb_convert_whatever()` functions because they suggest they can automagically do the right thing (which they don't) - too much reading. iconv(), string, two encoding identifier - done.

Comment: @MorHaviv see edit. What does that text say anyways?